# javascript with jquery and json - trying to extract and insert a numerical value

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm trying to use the following implementation of code, where the "areaofstudy" value will actually return a number in quotes. I'm pretty sure I'm going about it all wrong, or at the very least with the wrong syntax.

This is ad code and the goal here is to extract information from a stored cookie and convert it to a numerical parameter. The JSON code by itself works when I test it in a browser console. But when I try to get creative and use it in this ad code, the ad returns no results.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
vm_load({
"displayId": "12584", // Numeric unique ad display Id
"publisherId": "33927", // Publisher ID 
"campaign": "23193", // Numeric Publisher Campaign Id
"maxResults": "3",
"areaofstudy": "JSON.parse(jQuery.cookie('CategorySubCategorySpecialty')).CATEGORIES[0].text.replace('Business','1').replace('Criminal Justice & Legal','3').replace('Education','5').replace('Fine Arts & Design','2').replace('Health & Medicine','8').replace('Liberal Arts & Humanities','5').replace('Math, Science & Engineering','9').replace('Public Affairs & Social Sciences','13').replace('Religious Studies','5').replace('Technology','9').replace('Vocational Training','')",
"md": "1"
});
</script>
```

Comment: You've created a string, which happens to contain code. You need to actually execute that code. Remove the outer `""` around your `JSON.parse` line.

Comment: Thank you! That seems to have done the trick quite nicely.